# List comprehension example with different statements

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If I have next for-loop

```
a = 0
b = [1,2,3]

for x in b:
    print a + x
    a = x
```

is it possible to overwrite it in the list comprehension? My first attempt is fail:

```
a = 0
b = [1,2,3]
[[print a+x, a=x] for x in b]

    [[print a+x, a=x] for x in b]
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways to write this as a list comprehension, but you really shouldn't. Comprehensions are for expression-oriented programming, loops are for side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

As larsmans said, you *really* shouldn't do this. Crazy list comprehensions that use side effects are even harder to read & understand than well-behaved self-contained ones.

But if you're *still* curious, here's one of the various ways to do it. It utilises a mutable default function parameter to save state.

```
def adder(x, last=[]):
    if last == []:
        last.append(0)
    last[0] += x
    return last[0]

b = (1, 2, 3, 4)
print [adder(x) for x in b]
```

Clearly, this is more verbose and harder to read than the for loop, and I dare say it's also much less efficient. And it relies on a feature of Python (the behaviour of mutable default function parameters) that is not easy to understand by new Python programmers (and many experienced Python programmers aren't particularly happy with, either).

So **please** don't use this kind of craziness in your code!

---

**Edit**

Here are a few more ways to do this sort of evil thing with list comprehensions.

Firstly, a *horribly* inefficient way that uses `sum` on sliced copies of the sequence:

```
b = (10, 20, 30, 40)
[sum(b[:1+i]) for i in xrange(len(b))]
```

A similar piece of ugliness, this time using `reduce`. Guido hates `reduce` at the best of times, so I *hate* to imagine what he'd think of this monstrosity. :)

```
b = (10, 20, 30, 40)
reduce(lambda s,x: s + [s[-1] + x], b, [0])[1:]
```

And here are a few more that I devised a while ago, two using function attributes to save state, and finally one that saves state using a class, which is probably the least obnoxious way to do it.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Create an accumulator function from a 2 arg function.
    Like a cross between map() & reduce().
'''

def acc0(func, v0=0):
    def f(v):
        f.v = func(f.v, v)
        return f.v
    f.v = v0
    return f


def acc1(func, v0=0):
    def f(v, c=None): 
        if c!=None: 
            f.v = c
        f.v = func(f.v, v)
        return f.v

    f.v = v0
    return f


class acc2(object):
    def __init__(self, func, value=0):
        self.v = value
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.v = self.func(self.v, x)
        return self.v


def test(acc):
    g = acc(lambda u,v: u+v)
    print [g(i) for i in xrange(1,12)]

    f = acc(lambda u,v: u*v, 1)
    print [f(i) for i in xrange(1,12)]
    f.v = 10
    print [f(i) for i in xrange(1,12)]

    f.v = 1
    print [f(i) for i in xrange(1,15)]
    f.v = 2
    print [f(i) for i in xrange(1,12)]

    g.v = 0
    print [g(i) for i in xrange(1,12)]
    g.v = 100
    print [g(i) for i in xrange(1,12)]


def main():
    for acc in (acc0, acc1, acc2):
        test(acc)
        print


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Now that we've scared you good & proper, I'll show you a few more ways to do this sort of thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may not use print in a list comprehension. You should keep the for-loop instead.